# Secondary y axis with independent variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add one variable in `geom_col` plot along the y-axis. Both y-axes should be independent to each other.

I am trying make a plot on ggplot 2, with two y axis. One is Pval and second is size.

```
head(PA_filtered)
pathway        pval      padj         ES
4372             GO_REGULATION_OF_CELL_CYCLE 0.001663894 0.1459684 -0.2838682
4376 GO_REGULATION_OF_ORGANELLE_ORGANIZATION 0.001718213 0.1459684 -0.3099499
4380                    GO_ORGANELLE_FISSION 0.001779359 0.1459684 -0.3464745
4381              GO_CHROMOSOME_ORGANIZATION 0.001718213 0.1459684 -0.3276832
4382            GO_CYTOSKELETON_ORGANIZATION 0.001686341 0.1459684 -0.3180924
4383             GO_MITOTIC_NUCLEAR_DIVISION 0.001795332 0.1459684 -0.4149181
           NES nMoreExtreme size
4372 -2.215331            0   63
4376 -2.294293            0   56
4380 -2.388913            0   47
4381 -2.425557            0   56
4382 -2.455025            0   62
4383 -2.543914            0   36
```

[image]

```
ggplot(PA_filtered, aes(reorder(pathway, pval), pval)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=NES)) + 
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x="Pathway", y="P-value",
       title="GO biological process") +
  theme_minimal()
```

I want to have bars of factor "size" on the other left size.

[image]

Here is the simple form.

```
Df <- data.frame(A = c("x", "y", "z" ),
                 B = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03),
                 C = c(30, 40, 50))
```

X axis should have A( X, Y and Z)
Y axis upside B: (0.01, 0.02, 0.03)
and 
Y axis downside: C = c(30, 40, 50)

Comment: Hi. Could you possibly add a subset of the input data to your question (using dput) so that others can reproduce your example and build a solution from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I know add layers to a graph...The exact code may need tweaking for what you want exactly. Hope this helps?

```
ggplot(data=PA_filtered) +
 geom_col(mapping=aes(reorder(x=pathway, y=pval))) +
 geom_col(mapping=aes(y=size)) +
 coord_flip()+
 labs(x="Pathway", y="P-value",
   title="GO biological process") +
 theme_minimal()
```

Comment: it won't work. :::::: Error: geom_col requires the following missing aesthetics: x

Comment: geom_col(mapping=aes(x=pathway, y=size)) +

Comment: Thank you for helping. But, after this change, it only shows "size" on y axis. I want to have "pval" upwards on y axis and "size" downwards on y axis.   you can try on the simple data.

Comment: try using a different geom_........ this was just an example without knowing anything about your data.

Comment: I tried several different geom_ ways, did't work. Now I am making two separate independent plots and joining them. Thanks again for your input.